# Как удалить узел, если его имя содержит определенное ключевое слово?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

С помощью Xquery в sql server из xml нужно удалить все узлы, имя которых содержит "key". Как я могу это сделать?

```
<xml>
    <Node_key_node>
        Text
    </Node_key_node>
    <Node_node>
        Text
    </Node_node>
    <Node_key_node>
        Text
    </Node_key_node>
</xml>
```

Должно остаться:

```
<xml>
    <Node_node>
        Text
    </Node_node>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update #t
set col.modify('
    delete //*[contains(local-name(.), "key")]
')
```

Где `#t` - имя таблицы, `col` - имя xml-колонки.